# Magento - show order comments on a phtml

Tags: php, magento

i have bought a POS for magento.
My magento is running on magento 1.8.1 CE.

The POS produces a receipt through a phtml.
And than it will be printed. (on a 80 mm receipt printer)

But now i would like to add the ordercomments to the phtml

The base of the order is already loaded to the phtml:

```
$info_order = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getInfoOrder();

$entity_id = $info_order['entity_id'];

$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getOrderViewDetail();
$data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

But i can't get the comments loaded.

tried already (among a lot of other code found here):

```
$ordercomment = $data->getData('comment');
```

and in the body op the phtml

```
<?php echo $ordercomment ?>
```

But that doesn't work. The order which i am trying it on has a ordercomment.
Who can help me with this?

UPDATE 9-11-2014 16:46 PM (W-European time)
I tried the solution from jQuery Angry Bird:

```
<?php $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('pending','processing'));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $orderComments = $order->getAllStatusHistory();

    foreach ($orderComments as $comment) {
        $body = $comment->getData('comment');
        echo $body;
    }

}
```

And try to call it by using:

```
<?php echo $orderComments ?>
```

I now get all tranaction data from all the pending/processing orders.
But this order is already in the state shipped.
And i want only the comment which the customer has added to the order. Not the transaction history.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use following approach

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('pending','processing'));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $orderComments = $order->getAllStatusHistory();

    foreach ($orderComments as $comment) {
        $body = $comment->getData('comment');
        echo $body;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ronny Edit Question ,and tell wat u r getting

Comment: how to get selected customer order comment history using php script? @Pratik